# Find the joint pdf of X and Y for two uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, bivariate-distributions

Let *X* have a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,1)$. Given that *X* = *x*, let *Y* have a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,x+1)$.

Find the joint pdf of *X* and *Y*. Sketch the region where $f(x,y) > 0$.

Find *f*<sub>Y</sub>$(y)$, the marginal pdf of *Y*. Be sure to include the domain.

I'm not really sure where to start. Is *f*<sub>Y</sub>$(y)$ just $\frac{1}{(x+1)-0}$ since that's the pdf of a uniform distribution? And I have no idea how to find the joint pdf of *X* and *Y*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$ is $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{x+1}1_{0<y<x+1}$, hence the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is
$$ f(x,y)=f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}1_{0<x<1,0<y<x+1}$$

The marginal density can then be obtained by "integrating out" the $x$-variable:
$$ f_Y(y)=\int f(x,y)\;dx$$

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by *f<sub>Y|X</sub>(y|x)*=1/x+1 1 <sub>0<y<x+1</sub>?

Comment: This is the conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$. See here for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution

Comment: I think I get that, but why is there a 1 between 1/x+1 and the bounds?

Comment: That is a shorthand notation for 1 if $0<y<x+1$, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the bounds to use on the integral to calculate the marginal density of y. I believe $y$ should be the lower bound, but what is the upper bound? It can't be $x+1$, right?

Comment: The lower bound is $0$ if $0<y<1$ and is $y-1$ if $1\leq y<2$. The upper bound is $1$.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain that to me? I just don't know how to get that if the bounds on $f(x,y)$ for $y$ are $0<y<x+1$

Comment: We know that $0<x<1$ and $0<y<x+1$, hence $x>y-1$. If $y<1$ then $y-1<0$, so use the lower bound $0$. Otherwise the lower bound for the integral is $y-1$.